# PHP countdown timer without causing a spinlock

Tags: php, timer, countdowntimer, spinlock

**The problem:**

I'm a programming student and currently studying PHP. Apparently Java can designate threads for things like countdown timers; however, I have been told that PHP can have issues with a standard countdown function using delay, or even time() logic, as it will result in a spinlock. How do I go about avoiding a spinlock and having a simple, efficient countdown timer?

**Summary of what I am trying to solve:**

I need to create a 30 second timer on the backend PHP. Once the timer is completed, PHP will use my Slack API to communicate with a particular Slack channel - letting everyone know that the coffee is done, etc. With this said, I need to be able to start multiple clocks (as there is both coffee and tea) and must avoid a spin lock as it will kill the multi-countdown ability that is required.

**Code so far that results in spinlock:**

```
$startTime = time();
$actualTime = (int)$startTime;
$finishTime = ((int)$startTime) + 30;
var_dump($startTime);
var_dump($actualTime);
var_dump($finishTime);

while(($finishTime - $actualTime) > 0) {

    usleep(250000);
    $actualTime = ((int)time());
    if ($actualTime === $finishTime) {
       echo "Tea is ready!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you not just hitting the default 30 second timeout? Make sure error_reporting(-1) and ini_set('display_errors', true)

Comment: I think you are correct. I have only been testing the code with online sandbox testers, which only have a 3 second timeout limit. I was not aware of a default timeout of 30 seconds, but with that said I guess I would probably hit it when this project is completed.

That still brings us to the same question... how to code a proper countdown-timer in PHP that does not cause a spinlock?

Comment: I think I may have found what I was looking for. I am looking into something called ReactPHP. It apparently enables a timer without locking up the backend. I will post the solution if it works. Please feel free to offer other ideas or more info on ReactPHP

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);` will let it run until it finishes